# How to implement worker/keepalive thread combo in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Threads melt my brain. I've seen several different ways to implement a worker + keepalive model, but it's difficult figuring out the best approach. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
def start_thread(function):
    t = Thread(target=function)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

def worker:
    run = True
    start_thread(keepalive_fn)

    msg = recv() #blocking
    while msg is not None and run:
        process(msg)
        try:
            msg = recv()
        except:
            if run:
                reconnect()
            break
    else:
        if run:
            reconnect()

def keepalive_fn():
    while run:
        try:
            send('hb')
        except:
            close_connection()
            break
        sleep(heartbeat)

def connect():
    open_connection()
    start_thread(worker)

def reconnect():
    close_connection()
    connect()

connect()
```

Will this work as advertised? Is there a better way? Note that there is no mangled msg when close_connection() is called, as recv() already handles this case.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to enable a timeout on the recv() call, either by setting a timeout on the socket or using a select/epoll() call and using it to both issue a poll and time it out.  Pseudo:

```
bool timedOutOnce=false;
while(true){
  result=recv();
  if(result<>timeout){
       timedOutOnce=false;
       if (message<>serverPollReply) processMsg();
  }
  else
    {
      if(timedOutOnce){
         // server has not replied!!
         closeSocket;
         return(NoReplyFromServer);
      }
      else
        {
           // nothing received for a while, so..
           send(serverPollMessage);
           timedOutOnce=true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I meant that I already knew how to handle the recv() issue. My question is only about how to properly manage my two threads. I'll edit my question's wording to clarify.

Comment: I was trying to point out that you don't need two threads - you don't need to send the 'hb' keep-alive message if the server has just sent something, only if it hasn't sent anything for a  while.  Sending the 'hb' while the other thread is busily, and successfully, sending and receiving stuff is pointless and just wastes bandwidth.  Keep-alive messaging is actually much easier with just the one thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this use case, the recv() call is part of a third-party websocket module, which does not send heartbeats. I can fork the module to add this functionality, but that will create maintenance issues down the road. Also, I need a way to catch and recover (ie, close and reopen the connection, start new worker) in the event of a disconnection. Is my code the correct way to implement a worker and keepalive thread combination?